# Replacing Div Content Using innerHTML/insertAdjacentHTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of sections in a website I am making and I have additional HTML which I would like to swap out the initial content for once a button has been pressed.

I have done this kind of thing using jQuery and innerHTML/insertAdjacentHTML in tutorials before, but I can't quite grasp how to implement it into my own code. I understand how it works but JS is not my strong point and I am trying to learn a bit more about it by tackling these kinds of thing.

```
<section class="section-web new-section__white section new_section" id="web">

        <div class="row web-btns">
            <div class="col span-2-of-2 ">

                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#" target="_blank">Button 1</a>

                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#" target="_blank">Button 2</a>

                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#" target="_blank">Button 3</a>

                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#" target="_blank">Button 4</a>
            </div>
        </div>

 <!-- section (initial) button 1 -->
        <div class="row" id="button-1">
            <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                <h2>Text Button-1</h2>
                <p>Some Text</p>

        </div>

  <!-- section button 2 -->

  <!--
        <div class="row" id="button-2">
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
               <h2>text Button-2</h2>
                <p>text</p>


            </div>
        </div>
-->

 <!-- section button 3 -->

        <!--
        <div class="row" id="button-3">
            <div class="col span-2-of-2">
                <h2>text Button-3</h2>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
            </div
-->

 <!-- section button 4 -->

 <!--
    <div class="row" id="button-4">
            <div class="col span-2-of-2">
                <h2>text Button-4</h2>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>

        </div>
-->

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 180%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.new-section__white {
      padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #555;
    border: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here is a really basic CodePen. I have included the idea I have regarding how to achieve this in the JS field.

https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/XQpMNe

I know that I can use innerHTML or even insertAdjacentHTML using a constant, but again, unsure looking at existing code I have in another project how to implement into what I have written out. Mostly I can't understand how to call the function into view (excuse my terminology).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean about swap content? Hide/show elements realted to buttons? Or more advanced content swp?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'd want to hide the initial content and show the content which related to the corresponding button.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. If at all possible you should avoid any method that requires you to insert HTML. Since your setup for each different section is relatively similar, is there a reason you're unable to simply swap out the classes and content? Or is this more of an example of a more complex idea?

Comment: You are basically describing a "Tabs" UI. Should be easy to find lots of tutorials and examples on how to implement

Comment: @zfrisch the sections differ quite a bit, this was a stripped back example I provided. I am not entirely sure what you mean by 'simply swapping out classes', can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't want this to look like a tabs section, as this would affect the overall design of my site.

Comment: Looks are irrelevant. Tabs can have any look. It's the interaction of the tab selection (your buttons) and the content display that is relevant

Comment: @charlietfl Now I am looking at this with the examples given I might see if I can use tabs rather than JS. As I have a lot of content to do this with.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a button that interact with user, you should use button tag not anchor tag. 
Here is a code that works based on your example:

```
// button with onclick handler that calls a changeView function.

<div class="row web-btns">
  <div class="col span-2-of-2 ">
    <button onclick="changeView()" type="button" class="btn btn-ghost" href="#" target="_blank">Button 1</button>
  </div>
</div>

// identifier for paragraph tag

<div class="row" id="button-1">
  <div class="col span-1-of-2">
    <h2>Text Button-1</h2>
    <p id="some-text">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>

// changeView function implementation

const changeView = (view) => {
  const markup = 'asd';
  const p = document.getElementById('some-text');
  p.innerHTML = markup;
};
```

Right now markup variable is hardcoded as 'asd' but you can easily call changeView function with different 'view' for different button.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and see if it works for me!

Comment: Actually, I dont think this would work as I would end up having a million lines of code for all the markup I have to swap out across the site.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney not sure what you want extacly, but you can add second parameter to changeView function that will work as `const p = document.getElementById('some-text');` and then createElement inside function and append it to "p" - that way this function might be more flexible. Could you please elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have lots of sections with lots of different information and markup across a 1-page website, I had the idea to switch out the markup in order to group sections together under tabs essentially to minimise the length of the site, an example here of what I wanted to do: http://demo.agnidesigns.com/fortune/demo15/ under the Our Approach section. I am looking to switch out the entire section beyond the buttons (i.e colums, rows, h2s, ps) so not sure using insert HTML will even work at all

Comment: @CaitlinMooney it will work if you use markup with backticks like that - https://codepen.io/viciousandambitious/pen/jRyLBr

I believe it is good vanilla JS solution.

Comment: Yes this is what I had in mind, I think I noted that in my codepen also.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney if you don't want that much code, you can use some framework, but this is proper vanilla JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this in a few ways, but the simplest is just to use `innerHTML` and switch out the content.

The code below isn't the simplest way to do this, but it does mean that you can break things down depending on how you want to switch up the content.

```js
const markups = {
  intro: `<h1>This is the intro</h1>`,
  summary: `<p>This is the summary</p>`,
};

const getMarkupSwitcher = markupData =>
  element =>
    markupToUse =>
      element.innerHTML = markupData[markupToUse]

      
const markupSwitcher = getMarkupSwitcher(markups)
const switchMainDiv = markupSwitcher(document.getElementById('main'))

switchMainDiv('intro')
```

```html
<button onclick="switchMainDiv('intro')">Intro</button>
<button onclick="switchMainDiv('summary')">Summary</button>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and see if it works for me!

Comment: Looking at what I am trying to achieve I don't think this is going to work as I would have lots of code to swap out, I'll need to see what else I can do!

Comment: @CaitlinMooney why would you need lots of code? If it's only because you'd need to have lots of markup, then I think any vanillajs/jQuery solution will have the same issue. If that's the case then something like vue/react may be more appropriate

Comment: I have lots of sections with lots of markup to switch out, this was a very stripped back example I provided in order to get an idea of what to do/how to implement it.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney Ah ok; in that case, there's not really any way to switch out lots of markup without including the markup somewhere in the code. You could put it into the html instead of the js and just set which parts are visible, or you could look to use some sort of framework that makes these things a little easier and gives a bundle output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', (event) => {
    $('.content-section').hide();
    let section = $(event.target).data('section');
    $(`.section-${section}`).show();
  })
});
```

Since you seem to be using jQuery, i added a couple of properties to your HTML elements like `data-section='2'` to link the content to each button, you can also use libraries like Bootstrap that will generate this kind of menus for you.

Here is a fiddle with a simple solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wze9ksma/)